# How do I configure my Spring Boot (Kotlin) app to redirect / to /swagger-ui.html?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, swagger-2.0

I'm struggling to figure out what I need to add to the SwaggerConfiguration to get my Spring Boot app to automatically redirect requests to / to /swagger-ui.html

The current SwaggerConfiguration is like...

```
package com.climate.squirrel.web

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    open fun api(): Docket = Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
}
```

In Java, this was achieved like...

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/swagger-ui.html");
        }
    };
}
```

When I try to just guess at the Kotlin equivalent,

```
@Bean
fun forwardToIndex(): WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    return object : WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        override fun addViewControllers(registry: ViewControllerRegistry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/swagger-ui.html")
        }
    }
}
```

I get Deprecation warnings that I don't understand how to get around.

```
w: /Users/robert.kuhar/dev/squirrel/src/main/kotlin/com/climate/squirrel/web/SwaggerConfiguration.kt: (6, 58): 'WebMvcConfigurerAdapter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/robert.kuhar/dev/squirrel/src/main/kotlin/com/climate/squirrel/web/SwaggerConfiguration.kt: (26, 27): 'WebMvcConfigurerAdapter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/robert.kuhar/dev/squirrel/src/main/kotlin/com/climate/squirrel/web/SwaggerConfiguration.kt: (27, 25): 'WebMvcConfigurerAdapter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
```

How do I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Oh, geez.  I see.  This isn't Kotlin at all, really.  This is up-the-middle Java deprecation in light of Java 8 default methods.  If I swap out `WebMvcConfigurer` for `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, the Deprecations go away and everything just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't Kotlin at all, it is an up-the-middle Java deprecation:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html.

When you "Kotlinize" this in light of Java 8 default methods...

```
package com.climate.squirrel.web

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    open fun api(): Docket = Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()


    @Bean
    fun forwardToIndex(): WebMvcConfigurer {
        return object : WebMvcConfigurer {
            override fun addViewControllers(registry: ViewControllerRegistry) {
                registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/swagger-ui.html")
            }
        }
    }
}
```